# Android: Get audio URI from TITLE

Tags: android, listview, audio, uri, title

I have got myself into a tricky situation. I first fetch a media uri of an audio file got using an audio picker intent. But I need to display the audio title to the user. So I fetch its title from the below code and take it into an array list of strings to display in a list view since I'm allowing the user to select multiple files:

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public String getTitlePathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try { 
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
      } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

But my basic need is to set this audio file as a ringtone from another service. So I need to pass the media uri to the service rather than the title. Is there any way to get the audio uri from its title? Or is there any way associate another string value to an element in the array list but not display it in the list view?

I'm currently using a DSLV(DragSort list view) as my list view with the below code:

```
listView = (DragSortListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.item_layout, R.id.textView1, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setDropListener(onDrop);
            listView.setRemoveListener(onRemove);

            DragSortController controller = new DragSortController(listView);
            controller.setDragHandleId(R.id.drag_handle);
                    //controller.setClickRemoveId(R.id.);
            controller.setRemoveEnabled(true);
            controller.setSortEnabled(true);
            controller.setDragInitMode(1);
                    //controller.setRemoveMode(removeMode);

            listView.setFloatViewManager(controller);
            listView.setOnTouchListener(controller);
            listView.setDragEnabled(true);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create a map to keep reference of both title and corresponding path as well.

Comment: You mean to say a hashmap with title and audio uri as a key-value pair?

Comment: yes title as a key and uri as a value.

Comment: Isn't there any other better way? The external media uri may change on restarting the phone. So keeping a local key-value pair may not be a good idea. I want my app to be dynamic.

Comment: Are you fetching the titles once and storing it somewhere? or you are creating the title list each time user opens the app?

Comment: I'm saving the title list in shared preferences. I'm looking at the possibility of saving even the audio uri along with the title in the shared preferences. It is possible right? I'm saving the title with the key name as list_<id>. I will now save the audio uri too as uri_<id> so that both the titles and uri are mapped by the id. Should work?